# How can I proportionally distribute data into groups using Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a Postgres table containing peoples' names, their age, and the number of marbles they own. The example has only two rows for simplicity, but that could be more.

| name | age | marbles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 4 | 10 |
| Bob | 7 | 20 |

I would like to retrieve the number of marbles per age group, where the number of marbles is distributed to each age group, proportionally<sup>1</sup> to the person's age. The age groups can vary, but are known at query time<sup>2</sup>.

The output would look like this:

| age_group | marbles |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 *(1/5 of Alice's marbles)* |
| 5 | 20 *(4/5 of Alice's marbles, 3/5 of Bob's marbles)* |
| 10 | 8 *(2/5 of Bob's marbles)* |

Is there an elegant way of querying my table to achieve this?

---

<sup>1</sup>To be specific, the proportion of marbles per age group for one person would be:

```
marbles_higher_age_group = (age - lower_age_group) / (higher_age_group - lower_age_group) * marbles
marbles_lower_age_group = marbles - marbles_higher_age_group
```

<sup>2</sup>When querying the table, the age groups are known. They can differ over multiple queries and may be arbitrarily chosen. For instance, one query might use age groups `[0,5,10]`, while the next query uses `[0,1,4,8,12]`.

Comment: You have to explain the proportionality by age a bit better. Alice is 4/5's **on her way** from being 0 to being 5. Bob is 2/5's **away** from 5 and 3/5's from 10, so that is contrary to Alice's computation. Which one is it supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, you're right! I fixed the example.

Comment: If Patrick's summary of the proportions is correct, please add that info to the question to help the next guy trying to do the same thing, because comments can be deleted ...

Comment: Thanks @SOS, added a formula. If anything else would help, happy to add more info.

Comment: @TTT can you please elaborate more on age_group like will it always be multiple of 5 or if it is known then on what basis it is decided, is there any logic or just randomly chosen.

Comment: @TTT is age_group values present in separate table?

Comment: @NishantGupta, at present age_group values aren't present in a separate table. But, if that makes things more elegant, I could definitely create a table for it.

Comment: In your 2nd note you mention that *...while the next query uses [0,1,4,8,12]*, but you chose for your sample data [0,5,10] (equally spaced age groups) and this is totally misleading. Edit your question with sample data and expected results for the case of [0,1,4,8,12] age groups to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an arbitrary set of age groups stored in a table

```
select ag, sum(agm) marbles
from marbles m
join ( 
    select age_group low, lead(age_group) over(order by age_group) high
    from age_groups ag
) a on a.high >= m.age and a.low <= m.age
, lateral (
    select a.low ag , 1.0 * m.marbles * (a.high - m.age)/(a.high -  a.low) agm
    union all
    select a.high, 1.0 * m.marbles * (m.age -  a.low)/(a.high -  a.low)

) mm
group by ag
order by ag;
```

Alternatively you can provide an array of age groups in the query

```
select ag, sum(agm) marbles
from marbles m
join ( 
    select age_group low, lead(age_group) over(order by age_group) high
    from unnest(array[1,2,4,8,12]) age_groups(age_group)
) a on a.high >= m.age and a.low <= m.age
, lateral (
    select a.low ag, 1.0 * m.marbles * (a.high - m.age)/(a.high - a.low) agm
    union all
    select a.high, 1.0 * m.marbles * (m.age - a.low)/(a.high - a.low)
) mm
group by ag
order by ag;
```